# How to reload a page when it is on screen for the second time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, slider

I have a problem. I have a little jQuery app with a listview homepage that directs to a slider page. There you insert a value by using the slider. Then it passes it to the next page. On that page the number is presented. Now if I click on the back button in the upper left corner, I want to reload the homepage so that the slider has come back to its original position and that there isn't a number presented yet.

I was thinking of something like this, but it didn't quite work:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#homepage',  function(){
        if (number !== 0) {
           location.reload();
        } 
});
```

Here is my project:
http://jsfiddle.net/9ytwt/1/

EDIT:

I found my answer!!

```
$('#homepage').bind('pageshow', function() {
            location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading, which can preserve values in some browsers/webviews, you can try:
`document.location = document.location`, which basically forwards the page to itself, as if clicking a link.

EDIT:
Well first off, there are some major design flaws here. Reloading a page just to reset some inputs is not the right thing to do. Secondly, you shouldn't bind to `pageinit`, instead bind to `pagebeforeshow`, which is triggered every time just before a page is displayed.

In your code, you should change the page id to "pageWithSlider" or something similar, then you can use:

```
$( document ).on( "pagebeforeshow", "#pageWithSlider",  function() {
    $( "#slider" ).val( 20 );
} );
```

Which resets the slider, every time the page is displayed.

If you want to learn about different events you can bind to: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: yes, but the problem is that the the function doesn't work. If I link location.reload() to a button it works. So can you give me a working example with my code, please...?

Comment: You mean `document.location = document.location` instead of `location.reload()` doesn't work? If not, does it display an error in the console?
If you're using an older browser, you might want to try `window.location = window.location`, seeing that document is sometimes readonly.

Comment: No, I mean that the whole `$(document).on('pageinit', '#homepage',  function()` doesn't work. Check my jsFiddle in the question. Then you see that if you click a back button, and go to the slider page again, the value of the slider is still on your putted value and not on the standard value of 20, which it should be, because the homepage should have been refreshed.

Comment: Thank you for helping, but just resetting my slider value wasn't really my problem. I have a much more complex app; something which words learning. But if you finished the 'course' and click on the back button I want my app to refresh. I noticed that it works great by a page reload. So therefore I created this little slider project. Just explaining how to restore one slider value didn't solve my problem...